# Using extends with functional interfaces - Function<? extends Parent, *> vs Function<? super Parent, *> vs Function<Parent, *>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting, functional-programming

For the following three scenarios :

```
void check1(Function<Parent, String> function) {
    Parent p = new Parent(); 
    function.apply(p); // compiles fine
    Child c = new Child();
    function.apply(c); // compiles fine
}

void check2(Function<? super Parent, String> function) {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    function.apply(p); // compiles fine
    Child c = new Child();
    function.apply(c); // compiles fine
}

void check3(Function<? extends Parent, String> function) {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    function.apply(p); // compile time error
    Child c = new Child();
    function.apply(c); // compile time error
}
```

In the 3rd case, i receive compile time failure like this for **both** cases where Parent object or Child object is passed to the function :

> The method apply(capture#21-of ? extends Parent) in the type
>   Function is not applicable
>   for the arguments (Parent)

My understanding till now was : `extends` does mean "is or extends" but above cases lead me to following queries:

- Why does `Function<? extends T>` is not accepting child, parent objects ?
- Secondly is `Function<? super T>` accepting both child, parent objects
  due to the fact that *parent reference can hold child objects* (`Base obj=new Child()`) ?

---

Edit: 
I understand the PECS issue in collections (e.g list) like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) since there the `List<? extends Parent>` might get a *reference* to `List<GrandChild>`. Now, if we try to add `Child object` in this, it would have caused a **runtime error** if not caught by compiler earlier.

> Similarly is the Functional interface also behaving same & how are
>   reference maintained here ?

The functionality is explained by examples by [rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53544710/1750360) but just want a clearer picture compared to collections.

Moreover this works, which is fine but then seems like **PECS (Extends can't consume anything)** shouldn't be taken literally :

```
<T extends Parent> void check4(List<T> myList, Function<T, String> func) {
func.apply(myList.get(0)); // compiles successfully 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Why does Function is not accepting child, parent objects ?

Your argument `function` can be any method that takes either a `Parent` or a subtype of `Parent`, based on the `? extends` upper bound.  That means that `check3` can accept a `Function<Child, String>`, to which you cannot pass a `Parent`.  This is why there is a compiler error on the `apply` method; the compiler cannot guarantee type safety when the type of the parameter to the function is unknown.

There also could exist *any* unknown subclass of `Parent`, e.g. `Sibling` or `Grandchild`, which also extend `Parent`.  This means that `Child` cannot be an argument of `apply` either.  The `function` could be a `Function<Grandchild, String>`.

> - Secondly is Function accepting both child, parent objects due to the fact that parent reference can hold child objects (Base obj=new Child()) ?

This works because `? super Parent` is a lower bound.  This means that the `function` as an argument could be a `Function<Parent, String>` or a `Function<Object, String>`.  Because the function may take a `Parent` or even an `Object`, one can always pass a `Parent` to that function and call `apply`, so the compilation succeeds here.

Answer (score 0):

The actual parameter to `check3` *might* be e.g. `Function<GrandChild, String>`, as far as the compiler can tell, and neither `Parent` nor `Child` is a valid type for a method requiring a `GrandChild`.